# Kibana: Cannot create Dashboard after a new install

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I recently installed ELK stack (Elastic Search, Logstash & Kibana) on a VM. Everything works great, as in, the messages from Elastic Search go thru Logstash & show up as expected in Kibana. Only problem is that I am not able to create any Dashboards in Kibana. I keep getting this error:

```
Error on saving 'My dashboard'. Forbidden
```

I Googled, used other answers in StackOverflow & tried several recommended suggestions such as:

1. Setting 'xpack.security.enabled' false in elasticsearch.yml
2. cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
3. index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete: null

Nothing is helping. I have made sure that disk is not more than 95% full. Here's what I see when I run the 'df' command:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            16438908        0  16438908   0% /dev
tmpfs            3294068     1188   3292880   1% /run
/dev/sda2       51340768 43199000   5504100  89% /
tmpfs           16470332        0  16470332   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           16470332        0  16470332   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3         96128    96128         0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop2        123264   123264         0 100% /snap/docker/423
/dev/loop0        125312   125312         0 100% /snap/docker/418
tmpfs            3294064        0   3294064   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop4         96256    96256         0 100% /snap/core/9066
```

Any ideas? Note: All versions are latest.

Comment: Did you check elasticsearch log file? What’s the complete error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was indeed a space issue. When I switched to a new VM that has 300Gb of space this 'forbidden' message was gone. A bit confusing error message but now I know.